# How can I read RSS in VIM?

Tags: vim, rss

Would like to read RSS in VIM, but I haven't found a plugin out there.

You guys have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just used feedparser.py in http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2147 to get a trac servers timeline view. You need to have it installed and +python in your vim install. Although there probably other language libraries you can try if you're a ruby/perl guy.

A bit of vim script knowledge and you're there (check out the link above and steal what you need). And feel free to do whatever you damn well please with your own vim install :)

Edit: rather than dredge through that code... heres a condensed version for your vimrc you can expand on and make prettier

```
fun MyFeed(feed)
split
enew
set buftype=nofile
python b = vim.current.buffer
python import re
python import feedparser;f = feedparser.parse(vim.eval('a:feed'))
python for i in f['items']: b.append('%s {{{1 %s' % (str(i.title), str(i.link)));
            \b.append(str(re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>', '',i.summary_detail.value)).split("\n"))
setlocal  textwidth=120
norm gggqGgg
set foldmethod=marker

endfun
com VimRssFeed call MyFeed("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/566656")
com Slashdot call MyFeed("http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot")
com MyStack call MyFeed("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/59592")
```

Make sure you have http://www.feedparser.org/ installed

Answer (score 3):

Is there a particular reason it needs to be inside vim? There are multiple full-featured console RSS readers available such as [newsbeuter](http://www.newsbeuter.org/).

Comment: Actually, I will try out newbeuter. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

don't, it's not emacs.

maybe try feed2imap or rss2email to read rss items in your favorite mail client (e.g. mutt)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
:e http://whatever.com/feed_url
```

On my (Linux) system this uses `links` to dump the page to a temp file and reads it into Vim read-only.  It's not pretty but it's semi-readable.  See `:h g:netrw_http_cmd`.

But yeah this sounds more like an Emacs thing.  Vim is just a text editor.  :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for that: http://danielchoi.com/software/vnews.html

I have not yet tried it myself, but it seems to be what I want. I agree with others that Vim is not Emacs. Nevertheless, making Vim a bit more like an OS with editing capabilities would be pretty cool in my eyes.

Answer (score -1):

There is a plugin for firefox - [Vimperator](http://vimperator.org/trac/wiki/Vimperator) (courtesy of gpojd) - which enables you to use firefox with vim shortcuts and the like. Makes a significant change to the interface.

Comment: This does not answer the question.